# Return only first row with particular value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I realize that this has probably been asked a billion times, and I could swear I've done this in the past, but tonight I've got brain block or something and can't figure it out...

I have a database table ("t1") where I need to be able to retrieve only the first row where a particular value appears in a particular column.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
 id  | qID | Name 
---------------------
  1  |  1  | Bob
  2  |  3  | Fred
  3  |  1  | George
  4  |  1  | Jack
```

What I want as a result is:

```
 id  | qID | Name
---------------------
  1  |  1  | Bob
  2  |  3  | Fred
```

The only column I actually need to get out of the query is the first one, but that's not where the duplicates need to be eliminated, and I thought it might be confusing not to show the entire row.

I've tried using this:

```
select id, qID, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by qID order by qID) as zxy
from t1 where zxy = 1
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid column name 'zxy'.
```

If I remove the **where** part of the query, the rest of it works fine.  I've tried different variable names, using single or double quotes around 'zxy' but it seems to make no difference.  And try as I might, I can't find the part of the **SQL Server** documentation where it discusses assigning a variable name to an expression, as in the "as zxy" part of the above query... if anybody has a link for that, that's quite useful.

Needless to say, I've tried other variable names besides "zxy" but that makes no difference.

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WHERE` clause is applied earlier in the process than `SELECT`. Therefore the calculated column `zxy` is not available in `WHERE`. In order to achieve your goal you need to put your original query in a subquery or CTE.

```
select id, qid
  from
(
  select id, qID, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by qID order by qID) as zxy
    from t1 
) q  
 where zxy = 1
```

Output:

```
| id | qid |
|----|-----|
|  1 |   1 |
|  2 |   3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1c02/1)** demo

> [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)
>
> 1 FROM
>   2 ON
>   3 JOIN
>   4 WHERE
>   5 GROUP BY
>   6 WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
>   7 HAVING
>   8 SELECT
>   9 DISTINCT
>   10 ORDER BY
>   11 TOP

Comment: That did the trick... and it is what I'd done in the past that I couldn't frickin' remember. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Where Clause Execute Before Select Clause so You can not find ZXY in Where cluase

```
   with cte as
    (
    select id, qID, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by qID order by qID) as zxy
    from t1 
    )
    select * from cte where zxy = 1
```

Here is my blog it might help you  http://sqlearth.blogspot.in/2015/05/how-sql-select-statement-logically-works.html